# How to add a space at the beginning of the edittext in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to add a space at the beginning of the text in the EditText. So, even if users press the delete button, there is still a space at the beginning. How to check if the first character is space and if not, automatically add a space at the beginning ?

Comment: why don't you use `padding`? I think `padding` is much easier solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `startWith()` method of `String` Class to check your requirement.

```
String str = editText.getText().toString(); 

if ( !str.startsWith ( " " ) )
{
    // add space
    editText.getText().insert(0, " ");
}
```

you need to check the above condition in KeyPress Event.

Comment: if ( !str.startsWith ( " " ) ){
              editText.getText().insert(0, " ");  //add a space at the beginning
             }

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a TextWatcher, by overriding onTextChanged() and checking to see if the space is the first character in the EditText string or not. And if not add it.

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //do stuff
        String mStr = mEditText.getText().toString();
        if(mStr.charAt(0) != ' '){
            mEditText.setText(' ' + mStr);
        }
    }
});
```